# callbacks not firing when opening a magnific popup from another one

Tags: magnific-popup

I currently have a magnific popup and within that popup i have a link that opens another magnific popup. Something along the lines of:

```
 $('.logbook-entry-details').magnificPopup({
     type: 'ajax',
     closeBtnInside:true,
     closeOnBgClick:false,
     closeOnContentClick:false,
     callbacks: {
         beforeOpen: function () {
             $.magnificPopup.close();
         },
         open: function() {
             console.log('Popup open has been initiated');
            },
            beforeClose: function() {

            console.log('Popup before close has been initiated');
          },
         close: function() {
            console.log('Popup close has been initiated');

            },
         afterClose :function() {
             console.log('Popup after close has been initiated'); 
            }
         }
 });
```

After reading i found that callbacks on the second popup will not be registered until i close the original popup as opening the new one just replaces the content and actually doesn't recreate a new instance.

I am trying to figure out how i could have my link within my popup close the current popup before calling the code to open the new one so it can register my callbacks.

By the way, the reason I am trying to do this is i want to reopen the original popup after closing my new popup. If you happen to have a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So just in case someone needs this answered, i had to add the following code to my new popup.

```
// a button that closes the popup
$('#cancel-logbook-entry-btn').click(function(){
$.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
});

$.magnificPopup.instance.close = function () {

 //code to show the original popup
};
```

And then in the original popup i had to add otherwise it will never close the popup

```
 $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function () {
       // "proto" variable holds MagnificPopup class prototype
       // The above change that we did to instance is not applied to the prototype, 
       // which allows us to call parent method:
       $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
  };
```